# HTTP Redirect of Cyrillic URLs: this example works without URLs being encoded. Why?

Tags: nginx, redirect, 301-redirect, redirection

As per the https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5987, HTTP header fields should be returned using the ISO-8859-1 character encoding.

This applied also to the Location field used for the redirection.
However, looking at the following example, I can't figure out how the redirect work despite the URL is not encoded.

http://goo.gl/m5fDF0

I ran different tools including the Google Chrome Developer, and the location field is definitely is encoded, but using a CURL or software like Screaming Frog return a location written with cyrillic characters.
In theory the redirect should resolve in a 404, but I got a 200.

Any idea of how this is possible?

Comment: Eh? The URL is percent-encoded in the Location: header!

Comment: I can't see it ... that's why I'm confused.

Comment: But Google Chrome Dev doesn't return it encoded at all. It just spit out cyrillic chars too.

Comment: Huh? It shows me the percent encoding. I have no idea what you're looking at.

Comment: Sorry the location header in the response for Google Chrome dev is fine. It's the one in CURL that is not, it returns on cyrillic. Using a software like screaming frog it also return non-encoded chars

Comment: curl is decoding the URL before displaying it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Character encoding is applied to the URL before the percent encoding. This is usually done using UTF8.

Comment: @kasperd I'm well aware of that. What relevance does it have here?

Comment: So, in a nutshell you are saying that is the URL is encoded, a tool like CURL doesn't show it right because it converts it. This makes no sense. However, looking at the Google Fetcher I can see gibberish characters returned, which suggests me the URL is not encoded.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in fact the redirect contains octets that are above 7-bit (greater than 0x80 hexadecimal). Various application will convert those octets to various visual representation on your screen; that depends on what **encoding** they decide to use.

If somebody would use UTF-8 they would likely get a fine cyrillic text, but that's accidental; off-topic to the question.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2   states quite precisely that:

> Historically, HTTP has allowed field content with text in the
> ISO-8859-1 charset [ISO-8859-1], supporting other charsets only
> through use of [RFC2047] encoding.  In practice, most HTTP header
> field values use only a subset of the US-ASCII charset [USASCII].
> Newly defined header fields SHOULD limit their field values to
> US-ASCII octets.  **A recipient SHOULD treat** **other octets** in field
> content (obs-text) **as opaque data.**

and

> obs-text       = %x80-FF

This means, that practically any octets can be sent. The software that **displays** a header, for example a browser that converts the octets to some visible representation on your screen, should use ISO-8859-1 **for this conversion**.

But the server that receives the data in a HTTP session is also free to use the octets for his operations, which is something that does **not** involve displaying any visual representation on any screen. In this case HTTP server uses the octets to serve you a page. Since HTTP server just gets some octets of input and produces some octets of output, the "encoding" does not really apply here (the HTTP server never needs to convert bytes into something that it shows on a screen or on a printer).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. So, it's just a matter of "fortune" and entirely depends on the client whether they would like to attempt for a conversion. May I kindly ask you to let me know how you determined the type of octet used?

Comment: I've used simple and known tools for the job, so I could be sure they don't alter the data (real bits inside octets). The tools were netcat and hexdump - both are linux command line.

Comment: Ok thanks for the suggestions. Have tried the hexdump sending the IO context to the command e.g. echo -n одежда-для-самых-маленьких-1747/наши-рекомендации-1753/подарки-до-1-000-руб.html | hexdump -C, but the output is not really clear. Any hint?

Comment: Well, I mean, an hint in understand on how to interpret not how the encoding works :)